# How do I find a document's array, and only get the array

Tags: mongodb, find

- Database MongoDB
- Program Language Golang
- Data Driven mgo

Document struct

```
type Organizations struct {
Id bson.ObjectId `json:"_id"`

Name         string `json:"name"`
Area         string `json:"area"`
Type         string `json:"type"`
CustomerType string `json:"customertype"`
State        string `json:"state"`
LastUpdated  string `json:"lastupdated"`
Assigned     string `json:"assigned"`

Address `json:"address"`
}
```

Array Struct which is belong to Organizations

```
type Sections struct {
Name        string `json:"name" bson:"name"`
Upper       string `json:"upper" bson:"upper"`
Master      string `json:"master" bson:"master"`
Uppermaster string `json:"uppermaster" bson:"uppermaster"`

OrgID bson.ObjectId `json:"orgid"`
}
```

My query command

```
result := []Sections{}

collection.Find(bson.M{"_id": bson.ObjectIdHex(orgid), 
        "sections": bson.M{"$exists": true}}).All(&result)
```

Finally, I get a document with array.

But, I just want to get only the data of "Sections" array in the document.

What should I do ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand Go language + mgo syntax but I guess you can come up with something similar

db.collection.find({ _id : orgid, sections : { $exists : 1 }}, { _id : 0, sections : 1 })

Check out how projections are done here 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#projections